# Salesforce DX - Difference ScratchOrg and Developer Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx

I have one query on Salesforce DX if we enabled the ScratchOrg in DevHub(Enterprise Edition). Can i use the DeveloperSandbox simulataneously?

Because i heard somewhere once we enable Scratch Orgs we cannot able to use Developer Sandbox.

Regards,
VenkatsForce

Answer (score 7):

No, that's incorrect. Salesforce DX and sandboxes of all types are independent of one another.

Integrating DX and sandboxes together in a coherent development lifecycle process may pose some organizational challenges, but from a technical standpoint there's no reason at all you cannot use both.

Salesforce DX itself can deploy to sandboxes using the Metadata API, too.

Comment: You could do well with reading through the Adopting Salesforce DX blog series here as a lot of these questions are answered: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/02/getting-started-salesforce-dx-part-1-5.html